# Using a session variable from one java project to another java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, session

I have set a session variable in a java project (A) in eclipse. I need to access that session variable from another Java project (B) . Hence i need to import project A into project B and display that variable in a JSP page. 
My first question is :

Is this method possible to do ?

If yes, How can this be done ?

I added the java files of project A into the build path of project B.
I tried through the following steps but its not working :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import= "javax.servlet.http.HttpSession" %>
<%@page import= "com.constants.SessionConstants" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd%27%3E)
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <% SessionConstants sc = new SessionConstants(); 
          String a = (String) session.getAttribute(sc.USER_INFO);
          System.out.println("The value invoked is " + a); %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But getting the error as :

> only a type can be imported com.constants.SessionConstants resolves to a package.

Kindly help

Comment: is SessionConstants your class or is a folder?

Comment: SessionConstants is the class in the com.constants package.

Comment: What have you exactly added to your build path ?

Comment: First I tried adding the entire project. Later I tried adding the java class file alone. Say the SessionConstants class file.

Comment: lets say you have the classes of projectA generated in `<projectA>/bin/`, when you add dependencies in projectB, you only have to add `<projectA>/bin` in the build path and **not** `<projectA>/bin/com/constants/SessionConstants`. In Eclipse, you can add a dependence on another project in the build path (menu BuildPath>ConfigureBuildPath). Have you tried that ?

Comment: My project doesn't have bin folder. I tried adding source folder. But dint work !

Answer (score 0):

I would include an external project C and include a dependency A and B to C. Please notice if you use an object from a different war file, the classloader must be the same for the three war files, otherwise you will recieve an ClassCastException

Comment: But I am not receiving ClassCast exception now right !! Also I am not understanding your answer. Can you please elaborate ?